# Want to insert data into MySql using JQuery, Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to insert data into mysql using JQuery, Ajax and PHP. I made function for it but it is not working. Can anyone help?
This is my Ajax function.

```
function insertComment(textboxID, event, questionID) {
    var comment = $(textboxID).val();
    ajaxCall(questionID, comment);
}



    function ajaxCall(questionID, comment){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"insertComment.php",
        data:{Q_ID:questionID, comment:comment},
        success: function(data){
            alert('data Added in MySql');
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my insertComment.php code for inserting data

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "comments";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$Q_ID = $_POST['Q_ID'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments(Q_ID, C_Description) VALUES('$Q_ID','$comment')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_close($conn);
echo "done";
?>
```

but it's not working. Can you point out what mistake I am doing in code.

Comment: can you expand a little on the "it's not working" - is the ajax request getting sent ( use dev tools console to check ) or is the db not getting updated?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation. The ajax request is not sending to the PHP page.

Comment: Are you calling your insertComment function correctly on a button click?

Comment: yes I have tested it. It is also calling "Ajaxcall" function as well but, not proceeding further from $.ajax

Comment: @Dave I am calling the "insertComment" function on pressing enter button from keyboard. it is not calling on submit button click.

Comment: @Black_Swat can you provide your html click code?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy I am using onkeypress. I don't have a form. I have a simple textbox and I want that when I wrote wrote something in textbox and hit enter, the written data inserts into the database.

Comment: how you call this function  **insertComment**

Comment: I am using this code 
<input type = 'text' onkeypress = 'return insertComment(this, event," + questionID + ")' />

Comment: You are aware that on key press will fire on every single key pressed while that box is focused not just on a specific button press. So for example a sentence like this will update your database 200+ times!

Comment: I know. In insertComment function I am also checking the keyCode. ajaxcall will fire when the keyCode will be 13. But the ajaxCall function runs only to line $.ajax. it doesn't run further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `ajaxCall` is being called well, Why don't you try the following alternative, although there isn't much difference.

```
function ajaxCall(questionID, comment){
    $.post("insertComment.php", {Q_ID: questionID, comment: comment}, function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry dude. It's not working for me. it is not calling the insertComment.php

Comment: insert the following in ajaxCall before $.post... & let me know the output... alert (questionID+comment);

Comment: thanks man. I got the error. The id was not passing in the function. Massive thanks once again.